# Authenticate user with Cognito user pool credentials

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

How to authenticate user WITHOUT identity pool/IdentityPoolId, only with user pool credentials?
https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Example 4 in link above works only for/with identity pool,
when i call for example method

```
cognitoUser.changePassword('oldPassword', 'newPassword', function(err, result) {}
```

retrun me error from CognitoUser.js, string 602-604

```
if (!(this.signInUserSession != null && this.signInUserSession.isValid())) {
      return callback(new Error('User is not authenticated'), null);
    }
```

But when i call

```
cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {if (err) {
                alert(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());
```

It's give me session tokens.

How i'm trying to authenticate user:

```
const logins = {};
logins['cognito-idp.' + environment.region + '.amazonaws.com/' + environment.UserPoolId] = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
// Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
   Logins: logins
});
```

That give me error

```
Argument of type '{ Logins: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CognitoIdentityOptions'.
```

What i'm trying to achieve:

1) How to understand that cognito userpool user authenticated without identity pool?

2) How to authenticate user?

3) Object CognitoUser have 2 propreties:

- Session
- signInUserSession

What are they for?
How to use them properly?

P.S. When im using like this way, all works fine, but i need to achieve it without identity pool

```
const creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
IdentityPoolId: environment.IdentityPoolId, // your identity pool id here
Logins: {
// Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
[`cognito-idp.${environment.region}.amazonaws.com/${environment.UserPoolId}`]: session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()}},
{
 region: environment.region
});
AWS.config.credentials = creds;
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the change password function inside the onsuccess of authenticateUser function. It solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve in the first place? Identity Pool, Identity Pool Ids are used  in the context of Cognito Federated Identities. Cognito Federated Identities is used to vend AWS Credentials by federating with different identity providers such as Facebook, Google, or Cognito User Pools.

The SDK you pointed to is the SDK for Cognito User Pools. User Pools can be seen as a directory of user data that can be used for authentication and is an identity provider for Cognito Federated Identities.

The method you are calling for changePassword which is an authenticated method in the context of User Pools (the user needs to be authenticated). GetSession just retrieves the current user from local storage. What exactly is your use case, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for explanation, question updated,

 GetSession -> give me session tokens idToken: CognitoIdToken, refreshToken: CognitoRefreshToken, accessToken: CognitoAccessToken)

getCurrentUser() - give me user from localStorage

Answer (score 0):

I feel that for your Logins map, you have a map that contains an array while the example has just a map such as below.

```
            Logins : {
                // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>' : result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
            }
```